# read data from text file and filter content

Tags: java, file-handling

I have a text file which has some securities market datas i want to read the content of the file up to now i am able to read the whole content but what I need is read perticular lines not whole content and i want to store that perticular line data to store in variable how can I achieve this?

to read data from I have this code.

```
public void loadPartsDataCleanly() throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        Part compart=new Part();
        String line=" ";
        File partsfile=new  File("C:/Users/ATOMPHOTON/workspace/anup/parts.txt");//put your file location path
    Scanner partscan=new Scanner(partsfile);
    try {
        while (partscan.hasNextLine()){
            String mystr=partscan.nextLine();
            System.out.println(mystr);


        }
        partscan.close();
    }

    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    // TODO: handle exception
    }


}
```

}

Comment: How do you know which lines you want to read? are they always the 5th, 7th and 42nd line or do they have some special format? What data do you want to extract from them?

Comment: ya the lines are fixed like 2nd 3rd and 4th for 1st company and 1st line 2nd line and 3rd line for other companies ...

Comment: your program reads it line by line so you might want to add a condition inside your `while loop` to store that particular lines

Comment: adding counter might help to determine the current line number

Comment: i am new to java no idea at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your part from:

```
while (partscan.hasNextLine()){
  String mystr=partscan.nextLine();
  System.out.println(mystr);
}
partscan.close();
```

To

```
int lineNo = 0;
List<String> theOnesICareAbout = new LinkedList<String>();
while (partscan.hasNextLine()){
  String line=partscan.nextLine();
  if (isOneOfTheImportantLines(lineNo)) {
    theOnesICareAbout.add(line);
  }
}
partscan.close();
```

Somewhere you will need a function that tells you if a given line number is one you care about:

```
boolean isOneOfTheImportantLines(int lineNo) {
  //YOUR LOGIC HERE
}
```

You can add extra optimizations such as not reading all the file but stopping once you have all the info you care about etc. afterwards. First make it work. If it doesn't work, it doesn't matter how fast it doesn't work :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a cleaner java8 way of doing things (both from IO and String finding point of view)

```
public class App {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Path path = Paths.get("C:\\full\\Path\\to\\file.txt");

        List<String> stringList = getLinesThatContain(path, "IBM");


        System.out.println(stringList);

    }


// Note: No null-checking mechanisms
    public static List<String> getLinesThatContain(Path path, String match) {
        List<String> filteredList = null;

        try(Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(path)){
            // Filtering logic here
             filteredList = stream.filter(line -> line.contains(match))
                                  .collect(Collectors.toList());

        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            // exception handling here
        }
        return filteredList;
    }

}
```